# CSS to prevent text wrapping on specific words?

Tags: css

I have product models that look like:

EF 200

That appear in paragraphs of text. I want to prevent the model from being wrapped between two lines due to the space. What method can be used to prevent the wrap? Do I need to enclose it in a span tag and, if so, what CSS property prevents the wrap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">EF 200</span>
```

Of course if you're going to re-use that anywhere, I would break it out and make it its own class.

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

HTML

```
 EF&nbsp;200
```